# Getting Mouse like behavior on mobile device webbrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that I designed for both use on my phone and a PC.  Part of the UI is a table in which multiple cells adjacent cells can be marked easily by dragging a mouse with a button down across them ( using mousedown event from Js).  On my smart phone however, the browser tries to scroll the window when I drag across cells.  I've looked all morning and can't find the answer I'm looking for.  How can I make the touch drag behave like the mouse drag on my webpage.

UPDATE:
I have in each cell of my table onmouseover and onmouseclick events which trigger functions, if the mouse is down, a function increments a variable , and when the mouse is up it decreases it.  so when a mouse button is pressed down over a cell an action occurs. Below is how a cell of the table is made.  Below it are the functions bob and bob2.

```
{echo  '<td width="8" onttouchmove="bob(id)" ontouchstart="bob2(id)" onmouseover="bob(id)" onmousedown="bob2(id)"  id='.$key.'>'.$value.'</td>';}

<script>
document.body.onmousedown = function(){
                        mouseDown++;
        }

function bob(clicked_id)
        {
         if (mouseDown)
         { THEN DO SOMETHING }
function bob2(clicked_id)
       {DO SOMETHING}

 </script>
```

I feel like the jquery swipe event is what I want, but I"m not sure how I would implement it during the table setup.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phones and tablets do not use a mouse, thus your mouse events are not and will not be firing. You need to use `touchstart` and `touchend` instead.

Comment: that only partially works, and only when at max zoom out, so there is no scrolling.  Is there an event to sense when the touch enters an element like `onmouseover`?